# Show that $z$ is a root of unity

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to show that if $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $|z|=1$ and $1+z^{k_1}+z^{k_2}=0$ for integers $k_1<k_2$, than $z$ is a root of unity.

Here is my approach:
Suppose $z=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$. Then we have $$1+\cos(k_1\theta)+\cos(k_2\theta)+i(\sin(k_1\theta)+\sin(k_2\theta))=0.$$
This would require $$\sin(k_1\theta)+\sin(k_2\theta)=2\sin\left(\frac{(k_1+k_2)\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{(k_2-k_1)\theta}{2}\right)=0.$$
This would mean either
$$\frac{(k_1+k_2)\theta}{2}=n\pi$$
or
$$\frac{(k_2-k_1)\theta}{2}=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$$
so either
$$\theta=\frac{2n\pi}{k_1+k_2}, \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{k_2-k_1}$$
Now note that
$$1+\cos(k_1\theta)+\cos(k_2\theta)=1+2\cos\left(\frac{(k_1+k_2)\theta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{(k_2-k_1)\theta}{2}\right)$$
But now I do not know how to continue, because I would need the real part to be $0$. Any hints on how to continue? My guess is that it would be a $k_1+k_2$-root of unity. Also, is there an algebraic way/trick of doing this without resorting to using polar forms and trig identities? Thank you.

Comment: Consider $1+z^{k_1}=-z^{k_2}$ and take modulus of both sides.

Comment: @BobDobbs You can post that as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key point is that $z^{k_1}$ and $z^{k_2}$ are complex conjugate.

Indeed, since $|z|=1$, let $z=e^{i\theta}$ then

$$1+e^{ik_1\theta}+e^{ik_2\theta}=0$$

requires that $e^{ik_1\theta}+e^{ik_2\theta}$ is real that is $e^{ik_2\theta}=e^{-ik_1\theta}$ with

$$e^{ik_1\theta}+e^{-ik_1\theta}=2\cos (k_1 \theta)=2\Re(z^{k_1})=-1$$

therefore

- $z^{k_1}=-\frac12 +i\frac{\sqrt 3}2=e^{i\frac{2\pi}3}$
- $z^{k_2}=-\frac12 -i\frac{\sqrt 3}2=e^{i\frac{4\pi}3}$

---

Following your way, we have that the condition

$$1+\cos(k_1\theta)+\cos(k_2\theta)+i(\sin(k_1\theta)+\sin(k_2\theta))=0$$

requires

$$\sin(k_1\theta)+\sin(k_2\theta) =0 \iff k_2\theta =-k_1\theta +2n\pi \; \lor \;  k_2\theta =\pi +k_1\theta +2n\pi$$

then for $k_2\theta =-k_1\theta +2n\pi$ we obtain

$$1+\cos(k_1\theta)+\cos(k_2\theta) =0 \iff 1+2\cos(k_1\theta) =0$$

that is

- $k_1\theta =\frac{2\pi}3+2n\pi \implies k_2\theta=\frac{4\pi}3+2n\pi$

or

- $k_1\theta =\frac{4\pi}3+2n\pi \implies k_2\theta=\frac{2\pi}3+2n\pi$

which are equivalent, while for $k_2\theta =\pi +k_1\theta +2n\pi$ we obtain

$$1+\cos(k_1\theta)+\cos(k_2\theta) =0 \iff 1=0$$

Comment: How do you know they are conjugate?  For instance, $1+4i$ and $2-4i$ are not conjugate yet the sum is real. Is there any other reason?

Comment: @AadiRane Yes I understand your point maybe I need to explain it better. Since we know that $|z|=1$ then they must be complex conjugate. I try to clarify this point. Thanks

Comment: Even if that $|z|=1$, that does not imply conjugate since for example $e^{3\pi i/4}$ and $e^{7\pi i/4}$ sum to $0$ yet they are not conjugate.

Comment: @AadiRane I'm referring to all the conditions given of course, $|z|=1$ and $1+z^{k_1}+z^{k_2}=0$.

Comment: @AadiRane I've expanded and reordered the reasoning,I hope in a way more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Key fact is that, when $z$ is on the unit circle, $1+z$ is on the unit circle iff $z=e^{2\pi i/3}$ or $z=e^{-2\pi i/3}$.

Since $1+z^{k_1}=-z^{k_2}$ is on the unit circle, $z^{3k_1}=1$ and hence $z$ is a root of unity.

Answer (score 1):

If $|a|=|b|=1$ ( so $\bar a = 1/a$, $\bar b = 1/b$), and $1+a+b=0$, then $1+a= -b$. Take conjugates and get $1+1/a=-1/b$. Multiply and get $(1+a)(1+1/a)=1$, so $1+1+a+1/a=1$, $a^2+a+1=0$, and $b=\frac{1}{a}$.